# Rename JSON fields used by MappingJacksonJsonView in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using MappingJacksonJsonView to serialize to JSON a class, however, I'd like to be able to rename some of the fields from the default name based on the getter name.

This is because I've to output field names like "delete_url" and "delete_type" for jQuery file upload. I'm using @Jsonserialize annotation to hand pick the fields to serialize.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface Picture {

    @JsonSerialize
    String getName();

    @JsonSerialize
    String getDelete_url();

    ...
```

For instance, I'm forced to call a method `getDelete_url()`, while I'd like to call it `getDeleteUrl()`, but still output the key `"delete_url"` when serializing to JSON.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to qualify using [`@JsonProperty`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/index.html?org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html).

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface Picture {

  @JsonSerialize
  @JsonProperty("name")
  String getName();

  @JsonSerialize
  @JsonProperty("delete_url")
  String getDeleteUrl();

  //...
```

Comment: I am creating a web service using Spring MVC, which simply returns json reposne. This is not working in my case. It is taking name of the field only.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the [@JsonProperty](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html) annotation?

*"Defines name of the logical property, i.e. Json object field name to use for the property: if empty String (which is the default), will use name of the field that is annotated."*