# scala method name as variable name

Tags: scala

I want to define `case class demo(notify: String)`, but my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) complains that "notify  cannot override final member".

I know that `notify` is a member method of `AnyRef` and the IDE may confuse variable name for method name. I need a `notify` field, how can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you just call it something different? `_notify` would work.

Comment: I'm using jackson to map  from case class to json, since the structure of json cannot be changed(other service would consume the json data),  I have to use `notify` field in my case class.

Comment: That question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7893619/1296806

Comment: You can use [jackson-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) to customize the mapping, so that you are not required to have a value with the exact same name as in the JSON. It would become something like `case class demo(@JsonProperty("notify") notify_: String)`

Comment: Did you follow the other link? Then close as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the IDE.  A Scala class can't have conflicting symbols, whether or not they are methods or fields.  For example, the following won't compile:

```
class Foo {
    val bar = 1
    def bar() = "bar"
}
```

`notify` is defined on `AnyRef`, and furthermore it is `final`, so you don't really have any great options here!

You can name the variable something different, of course:

```
case class Foo(_notify: String)
```

If you insist on the variable name, you can also extends `AnyVal`, but only if you have exactly one `val` parameter:

```
case class Foo(notify: String) extends AnyVal
```

You might be looking for the feature that allows you to escape keywords with the grave accent:

```
case class Foo(`val`: String)
```

This would allow you to use a keyword (and some other normally illegal variable names) as a variable name.  This doesn't apply to your example, since `notify` isn't a keyword – it's an already used symbol on the class!

You can also come up with a solution where `notify` is private to the class, but that won't work with case classes or most reasonable use cases.

Comment: `case class Foo(notify: String) extends AnyVal` won't work either. I'm expecting something like using keyword as variable name, simply by adding 'keyword'

Comment: @vincentchou I've added an edit that explains how to escape keywords.  Also what do you mean `AnyVal` won't work?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but @Jesper have already solved my problem. I thought scala would provide some kind of mechanism to allow us use `notify` or `toString` as variable name, but it didn't. @Jesper provided another trait of thought by taking advantage of jackson annotation, which is very handy in dealing with this problem.

Comment: @vincentchou Ok – you should answer your own question then, and mark this as resolved!  And next time, make sure to ask your question in context so that a reader can better help resolve the issue.  A classic version of the XY problem – you were asking how to name a variable `notify`, but what you really wanted was a way to serialize an object in a certain way! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your use case, a field called notify:

```
scala> class X(private[this] val notify: Int) { def f = notify * 2 }
defined class X

scala> new X(5).f
res1: Int = 10

scala> :javap -prv X
Binary file X contains $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$X
[snip]
{
  private final int notify;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_FINAL

  public int f();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
[snip]
```

Comment: I know that class's constructor could have `notify`, but jackson cannot serialize it